# return values in newlines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

I can print each value in newline by console logging 3 times and without returning  those values but is it possible to return each value in a newline ? my code -

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let posCount =0;
    let negCount =0;
    let zeroCount =0;

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == 0){
            zeroCount++
        }else if(arr[i]>0){
            posCount++
        }else{
            negCount++
        }
    }
    
    return console.log((posCount/arr.length).toFixed(6),(negCount/arr.length).toFixed(6), (zeroCount/arr.length).toFixed(6));
}

plusMinus([4,4,-6,-3,0,0])
```

OUTPUT -

```
0.333333 0.333333 0.333333
```

Desired Output -

```
0.333333 
0.333333 
0.333333
```

Comment: Concatenate the values together with `"\n"` strings

Comment: or call `cosole.log` 3 times

Comment: @LouayAlosh re-read the first sentence in the question

Comment: @Pointy yes, it does. I was forgetting to use '+'